# Notation for functions

Tags: notation

I have a basic question about the notation for writing functions. Say that I have a function defined as

$$f(x) = g(x) - 1.$$

Is it then correct to write

$$ f = g -1?$$

Are there any problems with writing functions like this?

Comment: It is clearly amboguous: $f$ and $g$ can stay also for numbers...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: If it were *clearly* ambiguous to this person, they wouldn't be asking the question.

Comment: Just a note if you're trying this in school: even though it's correct for a mathematician, don't be surprised if you get points off for it. Some instructors will take points off for anything they haven't taught you in class, some might be worried another student who *doesn't* know the meaning of this will try to complain why you got the points and they didn't, etc...

Answer (score 43):

If you use $f$ as the symbol for some function, then $f(x)$ is the image of $x$ under that function, i.e. $f$ represents a *function* and $f(x)$ is a *number*, the result of $x \mapsto f(x)$. So it makes sense to write $f(x)-1$ as a function value where $1$ is subtracted from $f(x)$: there's no real risk on wrong interpretations here, this is standard notation.

However, you can also do *operations on functions* such as the sum of functions $f+g$ or the product of functions $fg$. In that context, you could interpret "$f-1$" as a *difference of functions*: the difference of $f$ and a constant function $x \mapsto 1$ (for all $x$), abbreviated simply as "$1$".

Note then that the blue $1$ in $f(x)-\color{blue}{1}$, a *number*, doesn't play the same role as the red $1$ in $f-\color{red}{1}$, meant to denote a *function*. This can raise confusion so only do this when it's sufficiently clear from the context what you mean.

Comment: I don't understand where the confusion comes from. You can't subtract a number from a function and you can't subtract a function from a number. So it is clear that 1 is a number in f(x)-1 and 1 is a function in f-1.   On the other hand, I find f(x)=g(x)-1 confusing (even if it is of course standard notation), because you don't know if you are defining f or if you are trying to solve for x.

Answer (score 26):

In $f(x) = g(x)-1$, the $1$ is a number. In $f = g - 1$, the $1$ is a function $1(x)$, the function that for any value of $x$ will always return the constant $1$. So long as you and whoever is reading your work know that difference, you should be okay to write it.

Comment: One problem with this is that $1$, in a function role, might in some contexts (namely, _linear_ functions) be construed to denote the identity function, rather than the constant-1 function.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, thanks for the very good note. I've never really seen $1$ refer to the constant-1 function, but that was what seemed to be implied in the OP's question. Normally, $1$, when used as a function, refers to some identity function (I've seen $1_A$, for example), but I have not seen this in the context of functions of a real variable. The statement "So long as you and whoever is reading your work knows the difference" applies in any case, however.